# NODE JS, PM2 and Nginx - 502 Bad Gateway on JWT token creation

Tags: node.js, nginx, jwt, pm2

So I have a NODE JS application which has a simple authentification with login and sign up. If I run it with `npm start` on server, everything works. If I run it with `pm2 start script_name.js` sign up works, both for success (ex. create user) and error (ex. user already exists), login works for error (ex. invalid password) but on login success, I get a 502 Bad gateway from Nginx.

On further inspection, I concluded that the problem was in part where I generate token:

```
if (result) {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    {email: user[0].email, userId: user[0]._id},
    process.env.JWT_KEY,
    { expiresIn: "1h"},
  );

  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "Auth successful",
    token: token,
  });
}
```

I changed that code to:

```
if (result) {
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "Auth successful",
  });
}
```

... just for testing purposes - and it worked.

Does anyone know what may be the problem? Why is token creation breaking the app?

**SOLUTION EDIT 13.08.2021.**

JWT signing is asynchronous process, and there is a callback available so solution is to send 200 status in a callback:

```
if (result) {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { email: user[0].email, userId: user[0]._id },
    process.env.JWT_KEY,
    { expiresIn: "1h" },
    function (err, token) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        message: "Auth successful",
        token: token,
      });
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke jwt.sign?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just changed it to async creation of token, and removed some error handling below this code and it worked!

Comment: Hi @IOOIIIO can you post your code? I am also facing similar issue and seeing your code would help

Comment: @Bikash yes, I changed the original post